# click button changing color remain same after reloading or restarted page

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I created anchor tag in which I use heart icon which change the color after click. But I want to remain same the color after reloading or restaring the page. when I restart or reload the page it comes back on their default color.

```js
var btnvar = document.getElementById('favorite')

function Fav() {

  if (btnvar.style.color == "red") {
    btnvar.style.color = "grey"
  } else {
    btnvar.style.color = "red"
  }
};
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite" onclick="Fav()">
   hello
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is interesting.

Now there are **multiple** possibilities:

**1)** You can use browser localstorage and save the ip address from where the heart icon get clicked

**2)** Follow the first process and you can use browser session/cookie concept rather than browser localstorage

**3)** If you need to make it proper programmatically then save the IP address with the country code on the click in the database table and have the process more dynamic and it will give you much benefits for the long run.
**Benefit like:** If you want to do the analysis from which country more clicks are happen then it will help you to find it easily

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to do the 3rd step

Comment: You need to make the ajax call and using ajax functionality you can save the information into the database. Now you can create a custom table in the database for having the process work

Comment: Hope my solution helped you :)

Comment: kindly please can you show me some example

Comment: If you find my solution is helped you, please provide Upvote. Thanks

Comment: Please do not beg for upvotes or accepts. In this case please show example code

Comment: For the example new question was generated and it was already get solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is unset (the `unset` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)) the color of the link when the page loads (the `onload` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onload))

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  document.getElementById('favorite').style.color = "unset";
};
var btnvar = document.getElementById('favorite')

function Fav() {

  if (btnvar.style.color == "red") {
    btnvar.style.color = "grey"
  } else {
    btnvar.style.color = "red"
  }
};
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite" onclick="Fav()">
   hello
 </a>
```

Comment: Sorry its not worked .color come back to default after reloading page

Comment: Here's the working example: https://codepen.io/ive/pen/eYKEvOp

Can you elaborate on yours?

Comment: is this example of remain changed color after reloading and refreshing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store changed color, Please check this code:

```
var btnvar = document.getElementById('favorite')

    window.onload=function(){
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("color")!= null) {
          
          // Retrieve
          btnvar.style.color = localStorage.getItem("color");
        } 
     }

function Fav() {
  if (btnvar.style.color == "red") {
    btnvar.style.color = "grey"
    localStorage.setItem("color","grey");
  } else {  
    btnvar.style.color = "red"
    localStorage.setItem("color","red");
  }
};
```

Demo
[image]

Because The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date, When you restart or reload, It will still keep the color. You can also store it in database.